# Angular UI-Grid changing columnDefs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-grid

I have a UI-Grid in my View and in some cases i have to show differents things and differents configuration (editable for example).

One of my column is a dropdownlist, but when I change grid columnDefs my dropdown column is alaways as a text and don't allow edit.

```html
$scope.grdComposicaoQuimica =
{
 showGridFooter: true,
 enableSorting: true,
 enableGridMenu: true,
 exporterMenuCsv: false,
 exporterMenuPdf: false,
 enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
 enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
 data: [],
};

$scope.atualizarCondicao = function () {
 if ($('#hdf-Operacao').val() == "I" || $('#hdf-Operacao').val() == "E") {
  $scope.grdComposicaoQuimica.enableCellEdit = true;
  $scope.grdComposicaoQuimica.columnDefs = [
   { displayName: 'Elemento', field: 'COD_ELEME_QUIMI', minWidth: 75, enableCellEdit: false },
   { name: 'COD_UNIDA_MEDIDA', displayName: 'Unid. Medida', minWidth: 80, editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
     editDropdownRowEntityOptionsArrayPath: 'UnidadesMedida', editDropdownIdLabel: 'COD_UNIDA_MEDID', editDropdownValueLabel: 'COD_UNIDA_MEDID'},
   { displayName: 'Mínimo', field: 'VLR_MINFA_ELEME', minWidth: 100, type: 'number' },
   { displayName: 'Máximo', field: 'VLR_MAXFA_ELEME', minWidth: 100, type: 'number' }
  ]
 }
 else {
  $scope.grdComposicaoQuimica.enableCellEdit = false;
  $scope.grdComposicaoQuimica.columnDefs = [
   { displayName: 'Elemento', field: 'COD_ELEME_QUIMI', minWidth: 75 },
   { displayName: 'Unid. Medida', field: 'COD_UNIDA_MEDIDA', minWidth: 75 },
   { displayName: 'Mínimo', field: 'VLR_MINFA_ELEME', minWidth: 100, type: 'number' },
   { displayName: 'Máximo', field: 'VLR_MAXFA_ELEME', minWidth: 100, type: 'number' }
  ]
 }
};
```

The property "UnidadesMedida" was loaded when I filled out grid data. For each row this property is loaded.

All of others configuration works, just dorpdownlist column don't.